# Linking from email to Xamarin Forms app using Rivets Nuget package

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, deep-linking, rivets

I'm using the Rivets Nuget package in Xamarin Forms to link from an email to my app.

The email contains a link in the format  "example://products?id=12345"
(see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-android/) for details).

However, if I send the email with this link, because it doesn't contain http, it displays as text and not a hyperlink, so it cannot be clicked.
Anyone know how to get round this?

Comment: Is the application running on a single platform?

Comment: cross platform but just dealing with Android first.  Looks like I might have a solution.  If I set the link as a link to a back-end node api I need to call, and from there I do some processing then a redirect, seems to work.

Comment: exactly, for a crossplatform implementation.. for a single platform implementation, putting the link as <a href="example://products?id=12345">test</a> doesn't help?

Comment: Are you using the HTML body of an email to send it? Like @hichame.yessou mentioned, you should be able to add an HTML link to the body of an email. Is this an HTML problem or a Rivets problem?